# How to link checkbox and radio with button to open page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to link checkbox and radio with button to open page in JavaScript?

For example : Chooses "one" checkbox and radio then click button to open page.This idea of includes everyone: Chooses "one" checkbox and radio then click button to open deffrent page.

Radio:

0   Level 1

0   Level 2

0   Level 3

checkbox:

[ ] Addition

[ ] Division

[ ] Multiplication

[ ] subtraction

### {button}

I have this code...{only radio is work}....I don't know how to connect radio with checkbox .

[enter link description here](http://www.ziddu.com/download/19672908/OnlineTestPage.rar.html)

Comment: They select a radio button, and then a checkbox (just *one* checkbox?) to select a page? How does the choice of which radio or checkbox define what page they go to?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple if to check if the radio or checkbox is checked. You can use your own method to iterate over them(maybe by making them all class and checking one by one then returning the ones that are checked?). But the `checked` returns a boolean of its checked status.

```
if(document.getElementByID('Level 1').checked){
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

David Thomas made a good point, the 2nd group probably shouldn't be checkboxes but also radio buttons instead. It doesnt seem logical that you should be able to select multiple choices in the 2nd group.

Anyways, I would listen for clicks and alter a link based on the user interaction.

Setup a link to be able to modify:

```
<a id="next-link" href="#">Link to Next Page</a>
```

Apply the listeners and functions to change the link on the fly:

```
function changeLink(){
    document.getElementByID('next-link').setAttribute('href') = "/"+goto_link_level+"/"+goto_link_category;
}

//you can specify defaults here too
var goto_link_level = '';
var goto_link_category = '';

//event listeners for groups
document.getElementsByClassName('group-1').addEventListener('click',function () {
    goto_link_level = this.getAttribute('value');
    changeLink();
},false);
document.getElementsByClassName('group-2').addEventListener('click',function () {
    goto_link_category = this.getAttribute('value');
    changeLink();
},false);
```

This will generate a relative link based on the values of the selected options.
Example: "/level-1/addition"

Disclaimer: code is untested but should work